# how to get inner xml tag values through java?

Tags: java, xml, dom

how i can find the "abc" from this tag through JAVA code and SAX parser.

```
<first name="abc">My Text<first>
```

for example i am using the java code given below to find "My Text" from the above tag.

```
NodeList firstNameList = firstPersonElement.getElementsByTagName("first");
Element firstNameElement = (Element)firstNameList.item(0);
String type = firstPersonElement.getTextContent();

NodeList textFNList = firstNameElement.getChildNodes();
System.out.println("First Name : " + 
       ((Node)textFNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
```

but i don't know how to find "abc" from `<first name="abc">My Text<first>`

I searched by myself but i didn't find my exact solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`name="abc"` is an [*attribute*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Key_terminology) of the `first` element.

```
String name = firstNameElement.getAttribute("name"); // "abc"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Although I checked this method before this post, but i guess i tried in some wrong way. but thanks you provides the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are using DOM (Document Object Model), and not SAX (Simple API for XML).

Once you have an element, you can access the 'element.getAttribute("name")' to get the value you want.